# CAML Query assistance

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, caml-query

I have a query I created using U2U CAML query. I am able to retrieve all the information within the builder, but when I use in VS I am returning everything seems like. Unless while debugging I am checking the wrong things. Need to verify that it is correct and should work in VS.

BTW, I checked the forum so it seems correct, may just need another set of eyes sometimes....code running together

```
                using (SPSite siteCol2 = new SPSite("http://dev.portal.net/it/dev"))
                {
                    using (SPWeb web2 = siteCol2.OpenWeb())
                    {

                        SPList groupList = web2.Lists["Approvers"];

                        //Write SPQuery/CAML query
                        SPQuery myquery = new SPQuery();
                        myquery.Query =
                            //"<Query>" +
                            "<Where>" +
                            "<And>" +
                                    "<Contains>" +
                                        "<FieldRef Name='Group' />" + "<Value Type='Text'>PO</Value>" +
                                    "</Contains>" +
                            "</And>" +
                            "</Where>";
                            //"</Query>";

                        SPListItemCollection items = groupList.GetItems(myquery);
                        Console.WriteLine(myquery);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could rewrite it as such:

```
myquery.Query =
    "<Where>" +
        "<Contains>" +
            "<FieldRef Name='Group' />" +
            "<Value Type='Text'>PO</Value>" +
        "</Contains>" +
    "</Where>";
```

Your `<And>` clause only had 1 argument to evaluate.

`(list["Group"].Value == "PO" && )` is effectively what your query says.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks....see, I needed another pair of eyes. I initally had two arguments, but was trying to use avariable in my query

Comment: No problem. I totally understand. I feel sometimes even just trying to explain your problem to someone else causes your "Eureka!" moment.